# How to Replace Android Volley Library Using Gradle?

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley

I have Volley Library inside my Project (under **libraries/volley**), However i prefer to use Gradle version of volley library (https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley). I want to use "compile com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19" in build.gradle

But everytime i deleted Volley File Library then i got error message when compiled : **Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.**

How to replace existing Volley Library and use gradle version ?

Thanks before...

Comment: try compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

Comment: I've tried it, then appear error : "**Error:(263, 37) error: reference to JsonObjectRequest is ambiguous, both constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,String,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest and constructor JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) in JsonObjectRequest match**"

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105222/compililation-error-while-using-jsonobjectrequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19-SNAPSHOT'`

Use

`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: hi, i've used it. but now getting error as same as on my first comment

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105222/compililation-error-while-using-jsonobjectrequest)?

Comment: Yes, i've read that post and replaced **jsonObjectRequest**, but come with this error : "**Error:(267, 35) error: cannot find symbol method getRequestUrl(int)**" any idea ?

Comment: replace `getRequestUrl(int)` with your `URL`.

Comment: Thanks it works! but the last one, everytime i deleted volley file library, i get error "**Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':twb'.
> Cannot evaluate module volley : Configuration with name 'default' not found.**"   Do i need to delete module Volley ?

Comment: Found Solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio), I will mark your answer as accepted...btw, thank you very much...